# Where in database does python-social-auth store access token?

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-login, python-social-auth

I am using `python-social-auth` (within django) to implement facebook-login. I am able to successfully sign into my app using facebook and extract user email. But where in the database can I find the OAuth token generated by facebook? Is it in the password field in the user table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [UserSocialAuth extra_data field](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py#L34) which is a JSONField.

Example of the value stored:

```
{"expires": "5184000", "id": "00000000000000000", "access_token": "the-token-value"}
```